# Is it possible byPass proxy settings configured in rimpublic.property of MDS simulator in Blackberry

Tags: http, blackberry

Our company uses a proxy server for accessing internet. For accessing intranet sites, we  bypass this proxy server.

I have configured proxy settings in rimpublic.property for  MDS and set the values for below fileds under [HTTP HANDLER]

```
application.handler.http.proxyEnabled = true
application.handler.http.proxyHost=***.***.***.*** ( ProxyServer IP Address)
application.handler.http.proxyPort=8080
application.handler.http.proxyUser=*******@****** (username@domain)
application.handler.http.proxyPass=************ (password)
```

Is it possible to bypass these proxy server settings (same as we do in internet explorer)  in rimpublic.property file for MDS simulator so that I can access both internet and intranet sites from my blackberry simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I have none of those settings configured, so it should be safe to just delete them (or comment them out with #'s) Then try again. If that doesnt work it might be using your systems proxy settings, so go to internet explorer options, disable the proxy settings there and try again.

Hope this helps